# Give blinking effect on overlapping image/panels in c#.net Windows Application

Tags: c#, blink

I am developing an application using c#.net windows form application. I have a form size background image & multiple star images. I tried picturebox control/panel as background for a large background image. Star images will be placed on background image & I want to give a blinking effect to those star images. It is working fine(blinking), if star the image is in individual picturebox control/panel, but when put on the background image/panel, it is not working... & if I place image on image, it is showing background also though it is set as transparent...can anybody tell me the solution.?

Code used for blinking effect

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox2.Visible = !pictureBox2.Visible;
    pictureBox3.Visible = !pictureBox3.Visible;
    panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible;
    panel3.Visible = !panel3.Visible;
```

Comment: You need to be a little clearer about the layout of things: How are these elements nested or are they just overlaid/overlapping? - There are quite limited opotions for transparency in winforms, in short : It is faked and only works for nested controls. - Also note the pictureboxes ( as opposed to panels..)  are not contaiers and to nest anything in it you need code!

Comment: In winapi (winforms is just a wrapper) transparency is far from being ideal (as opposed to wpf), afair overlapped areas of controls aren't validated all the way down. Since you have images you can [draw them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) one on top of another manually in `Paint` event of just one panel (or rather a form). Use timer to toggle `bool` field controlling visibility of one and invalidate panel/form to achieve blinking effect.

Comment: The code you need to nest a control in another one is `ctl2.Parent = ctl1;` - To nest in a Panel (or other containers like GroupBox) you can also simply place a control over it in the designer

Comment: These elements are not nested.Multiple star images are placed on single background image.I want to blink those star images.I already tried it with timer control.but plz tell me how to do it with paint event